# Iphone - grid of pictures using scroll view and ad UIImageViews to it

Tags: iphone, view, scroll

Can someone give me one source file working ?

Comment: What did [google](http://google.com) say?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at Facebook's [Three20](https://github.com/facebook/three20), specifically their [TTPhotoViewController](http://github.com/facebook/three20/blob/master/src/Three20UI/Headers/TTPhotoViewController.h) class.

Update: Other options (possibly more modular and easier to integrate in your project):

- https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser
- https://github.com/kirbyt/KTPhotoBrowser
- http://github.com/alanQuatermain/AQGridView (as suggested by Jim)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can look at my [AQGridView](http://github.com/alanQuatermain/AQGridView), which can display anything in a grid, using an API similar to that of `UITableView`.